# Add additional cost to path depending on label of edge

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a graph with some edges. Each edge has a weight/cost and also a label/type, which could be `red` and `green`.

I know that if I run Dijkstra's algorithm it will find the shortest/cheapest path from the weights of all edges. However, my issue is that depending on which type of edge it chooses, additional cost should be added. In principle, the additional cost should only be added each time a new type is used.

So for example if the path I find from Dijkstra's is:

```
node1  --->  node2  --->  node3  --->  node4  ----->  node5  ----->  node6

|---- edge1  --|-- edge2 ---|--- edge3 --|--- edge4 ----|--- edge5 ----|

   type = red    type = red   type = red   type = green   type = green
```

The additional cost added should then be added according to this setup/logic:

```
for i, edge in enumerate(path.edges):
    if edge[i].type == edge[i+1].type:
        <do not add any additional cost>
    elif edge[i].type != edge[i+1].type:
        <add additional cost to [i] edge>
```

So the additional cost should only be added if there is a change between types within the path.

I have no idea if this is even possible to do in any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply Dijkstra's algorithm to a modified version of the graph which will account for the additional costs:

- Duplicate every node in the graph, so that every node `v` in the old graph corresponds to a green node `v_g` and a red node `v_r` in the new graph;
- The new node `v_g` will get every green edge from `v`;
- The new node `v_r` will get every red edge from `v`;
- In addition, add one edge linking `v_g` to `v_r`, with weight `<add additional cost to [i] edge>` from your code.

[image: building the new graph]

Another way to think of this construction is to imagine that you have two copies of the original graph: the red graph and the green graph; both graphs have all the nodes, but each graph only has the edges of the right colour; and there is one extra black edge connecting each node from the red graph to the corresponding node from the green graph.

**Start of the path:** The node where the path begins plays a special role in the Dijkstra algorithm. Since the start node has now been divided into two nodes `start_r` and `start_g`, how do you know which node to start Dijkstra from? You could run the algorithm twice, once from `start_g` and once from `start_r`, and keep the smallest solution; but there is a better solution. Since the shortest path will have no cycle, you can set the weight on the edge between `start_r` and `start_g` at 0 instead of the weight used for the other nodes; the shortest path will not use this edge, except possibly once as the very first edge of the path.

Note that the end node doesn't play any special role in the Dijkstra algorithm (Dijkstra actually computes the shortest distances from the start node to every other node); so you don't need to worry about the end node.

Now you can run regular Dijkstra algorithm on the new graph.

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't thought of that. Let me try to implement that. But, then the original nodes and edges should be removed from the new graph, right, so it only contains v_g and v_r nodes and edges +

Comment: @DenverDang I added a picture

Comment: Hi again, after trying this out there might be a problem (or maybe I have just misunderstood something). But assuming I have a more advanced graph with multiple nodes as `v` in this case, i.e. having both red and green edges going to/from it. How does one choose the correct `v` ? I mean, all I know in advance is that it should go from or to the node `v`, but if the shortest route is by using `v_r` it would add additional cost if I were to pick `v_g` instead, since it will have to go through the `v_r` / `v_g` intersection.

Comment: I may have found a solution by just adding the chosen source and sink nodes to the new graph with their original names, but with an edge to either the red or green node, or both, with an edge weight of 0.

Comment: @DenverDang Yes! Well done for the extra source and sink nodes, I forgot about that in the construction.

Comment: @DenverDang Note that you could put an edge of weight 0 between `start_r` and `start_g` and use any of the two as the start node, rather than adding an extra start node connected to both of them. Also note that in the Dijkstra algorithm, the start node plays a special role, but the end node doesn't, so you don't need to worry about the weight of the edge between `end_r` and `end_g`.

Comment: Once again, thank you for your insights. So far it has been very helpful. However, I am now in a bit of conundrum, and I thought about creating another question, but you kind of already have an understanding of at least this. The issue now is, that I am trying to create node disjoint paths, where I have followed this "formula": http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Disjoint_Path_Finding (Suurballe's algorithm). The issue now is that doing what you said, nodes are now split into two (although they were the same originally). However, if a red node is used now, the green node can still be visited.

Comment: ... which it shouldn't. So the conundrum is now that your way gave me the additional cost between red and green, which is great, but now red and green are not considered the same node. This means that in the case of this Suurballe algorithm, it doesn't really work, since the same node are really two different node (although they should in theory be considered the same). And in turn this means that the same node can be visited - which it shouldn't.

Comment: That is an extremely interesting question! I think you should ask a new question, perhaps on cs.stackexchange.com where you might find more answers that here. If you keep the transformation with split nodes, then one keyword of interest is "Shared Risk Node Groups", for instance https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.192.4074&rep=rep1&type=pdf "Datta, Pallab, and Arun K. Somani. "Diverse routing for shared risk resource groups (SRRG) failures in WDM optical networks." First International Conference on Broadband Networks. IEEE, 2004."

Comment: If you do ask a new question, please drop a comment here with the link so I can find it :)

Comment: When you ask the new question, keep in mind that there are at least two approaches to your problem: 1) keep the split nodes, and find "(node group)-disjoint paths"; 2) don't split the nodes, and find another way to account for the cost of switching between red and green.

Comment: Again, thank you for your interest in this :) I have now submitted a new question on cs, with the link: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141865/node-disjoint-paths-with-node-splitting